# how to reduce the website image to 2-5kb per for an ecommerce website?

Tags: image, image-processing, cdn

I am not a tech guy but running a fully customized ecommrece website, based on Next/js & express/js. I have noticed some websites are using super compressed images (imageglass avif file or webp), but we have to use images 50-60k per, so what's the technology in it? we are using Cloudary as CDN to manage images, but still the images would be jpeg or PNG, I have no idea that how to convert images into smaller sizes but withhout to much compromise to the quality.

this is my first question, hopefully, I can have some insights from your guys.
Cheers

I have tried to google for the answer, but it doesn't work, and tried to discuss the issue with some developers, but they can't give me a specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some selection tools to compress images.

[Some image compression tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=website%20image%20compression%20tools&oq=website%20compress%20im&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCAgDEAAYFhgeMgcIABAAGIAEMgYIARBFGDkyCggCEAAYDxgWGB4yCAgDEAAYFhgeMggIBBAAGBYYHjINCAUQABiGAxiABBiKBTINCAYQABiGAxiABBiKBdIBCTM5MzExajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Personally I use this tool all the time.](https://imagecompressor.com/)